# Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $A$ but a subset of $X$ then $Int(Bd(A)) = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $A$ but a subset of $X$ then $Int(Bd(A)) = \emptyset$

I need to decide if this is true or not.  I have done a little research and some contemplating and I believe this statement is true for open sets but I am not sure if it is true for closed sets or if I am overthinking and do not need to consider both sets. I am wondering if I am overthinking and this is true and a proof by contradiction would work?

My definition of interior is: Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $A \subset X$ is the set of all points $x \in X$ for which there exists an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq A$.

My definition of boundary is: Let $(X,\mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$. A point $x \in X$ is in the boundary of A if every open set containing $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X−A$.

Comment: It might be the case $A$ is neither open nor closed.  Consider what happens when $X = \Bbb R$ and $A = \Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X=\Bbb R$ and $A= \Bbb Q$, then $\operatorname{Bd}(A)=\operatorname{Bd}(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R$ so $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Bd}(A))=\operatorname{Int}(\Bbb R)\neq \emptyset$, so the proposition doesn't hold for every set $A$.

Comment: Is the interior of $\mathbb R$= $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace That's right, any idea of why is that the case?

Comment: well its an open set so the interior is the open set that contains the set so it would have to be the reals?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace More generally, *the interior of an open set equals the set* (in every topological space).